# Make one child div expand the parent's width and second child just fill the parent

Tags: css

There is a **parent** div with 2 children - **child1** and **child2**.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2">
        <p>Some long text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the **parent** to expand it's width by the **child1** div (e.g. if child1 has width=200px, parent has the same width).

Below child1, there should be the **child2** div and fill 100% of the parent's width (set by **child1**), but not expand the parent's width further (e.g. if there is a long paragraph of text, it should wrap on 200px).

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on parent

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Nope, have tried that - but parent width is then further expanded by child2.

Comment: Does `child1` have a set hight?

Comment: @TJ No it doesn't - child1 contains multiple nested inline-blocks and expands based on their number. Child1 is like a train with some number of wagons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `min-content` on your parent's `max-width`. This will reduce the maximum width to the smallest word it can fit. Then you set the width of your first child to `max-content` in order to force the parent to expand to this set width.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: min-content;
}

.child1 {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">The width should stop here</div>
    <div class="child2">
        <p>Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed as duplicate. The solution in the duplicated answer offers a hack with inline-block and width zero. My solution has no hacks and works as intended in all modern browsers.

Comment: I'm with you, checked the other solution and yours is so much clearer.